# With Eclipse rcp, how to create a button with a drop down menu?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to create a button (on the toolbar in a view), which will present a drop down menu when clicked on. This is similar to the lists of perspectives that gets displayed when the perspective button is clicked on.

[image]

If someone can provide code examples it would be helpful.  I am working with Eclipse 3.6

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113313/swt-button-dropdown-control

Comment: Take a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html#commands_toolbardropdown